# "Can't correlate an artifact" when trying to promote a snapshot release on oss.jfrog.org

Tags: artifactory, bintray

I'm trying to set up an automated snapshot and release chain for an open source Java library.

This is the intended setup:

1. Travis CI checks out the Github project
2. Travis CI runs the Gradle build
3. The Gradle build uses the artifactory plugin to publish a snapshot on oss.jfrog.org
4. Travis CI calls the artifactory REST API to promote the snapshot from step 3 to be released to bintray

Everything including step 3 works. When trying to promote the snapshot as described [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Snapshots+to+oss.jfrog.org#DeployingSnapshotstooss.jfrog.org-PromotingaBuildUsingRESTAPI), however, I always get the following response from the oss.jfrog.org artifactory server:

`Request has been canceled: Can't correlate an artifact diffparser-1.4-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to the build being promoted. Check that the artifact was created by the build you are trying to promote.`

However, my build produces the javadoc and sources jar correctly, and they have been successfully published (see [here](https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/oss-snapshot-local/io/reflectoring/diffparser/diffparser/1.4-SNAPSHOT)). So I don't understand the error.

Does anyone have a clue as to what I might be missing?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your snapshots on OJO, it appears that most of the artifacts in the referenced location) do not have properties on them (i.e. build.name + build.number) which associate them with your build. If you will go to the Builds section you will see that the latest build that have artifact association is build number '1513800489095' (which also differ from your other builds (14,15,16,etc..)).
You will need to make sure that your [(Gradle) build](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) is deploying the build's artifacts with properties .
In addition, I would highly recommend to switch to use the [JFrog CLI's Maven and Gradle Builds](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningMavenandGradleBuilds) feature ([JFrog CLI is an OSS project](https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go)).

p.s. I work at JFrog

Comment: I was hoping to catch one of you guys here :). Thanks for the answer. I will look into that and get back to you :)